# SQL Query to compare two values which are in the same column but returned by two different set of queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the one shown below.

```
-----------------------------
JOB ID | parameter | result |
-----------------------------
1       | xyz      | 10     |
1       | abc      | 15     |
2       | xyz      | 12     |
2       | abc      | 8      |
2       | mno      | 20     |
-----------------------------
```

I want the result as shown below.

```
 parameter | result 1 | result 2 |
----------------------------------
   xyz     |  10      |  12      |
   mno     |  NULL    |  20      |
   abc     |  15      |  8       |
----------------------------------
```

My goal is to have a single table which can compare the result values of two different jobs. It can be two or more jobs.

Comment: What happens if there are three `xyz`s in the table? And is the third row in your sample result set supposed to be `abc`?

Comment: what is it? mysql? postgresql? sqlserver? they all have different syntax

Comment: @muistooshort he wants a pivot table off of job id. the parameters are optional

Comment: its mysql. Will update the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to simulate a pivot table since mysql doesn't have pivots.

```
select 
    param, 
    max(case when id = 1 then res else null end) as 'result 1',
    max(case when id = 2 then res else null end) as 'result 2'
from table
group by param
```

[SQL FIDDLE TO PLAY WITH](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2c6d/6)

Comment: What if the result is text not a number?

Comment: @JasonLou ? what are you asking? the id is always a number. the result is what gets returned if we are on the correct id. What is your question about that?

Comment: Still, not sure where you are going with this. the result can be a string or a number it doesnt matter. look here. I changed them all to strings. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38ecf/1 ... or even with letters . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7cb7/1 not sure where you are going with this. the case just returns the item. max returns the element that is not null and there is only one in every case so you get the value that is in the tables row

Comment: Give a point to you. Basically I do sql in MSSQL. That is not allow max compared in char type.

Comment: ah gotcha, yes each engine treats things differently. MySQL allows a max to look at the difference between a value and null :)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use something like:

```
select parameter, (array_agg(result))[1], (array_agg(result))[2] from my_table group by parameter;
```

The idea is: aggregate all the results for a given parameter into an array of results, and then fetch individual elements from those arrays.

I think that you can achieve something similar in MySQL by using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, although it returns a string instead of an array, so you cannot easily index it. But you can split by commas after that.

Comment: I asked which engine he was using sine it was tagged multiple and he said its mysql so sadly this isn't the correct answer :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL there are no "outer join" need to use union right and left join:
Something like:

```
select t1.parameter, t1.result 'Result 1', t2.result 'Result 2' from
table as t1 left join table as t2
on t1.parameter=t2.parameter
where t1.'JOB ID' = 1 and t2.'JOB ID' = 2
union
select t1.parameter, t1.result 'Result 1', t2.result 'Result 2' from
table as t1 right join table as t2
on t1.parameter=t2.parameter
where t1.'JOB ID' = 1 and t2.'JOB ID' = 2
```

If the SQL with full outer join will make it more easier:

```
select t1.parameter, t1.result 'Result 1', t2.result 'Result 2' from
table as t1 outer join table as t2
on t1.parameter=t2.parameter
where t1.'JOB ID' = 1 and t2.'JOB ID' = 2
```

Comment: I dont have two tables. t1 and t2 are the same.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to make self join with one name in query. but just want to make a self join.

Comment: self join is not the way to go here. self join wont be a good solution when you need to return 10, 20 columns. dont want to self join that many times

Comment: Amal Ts: I make One table self join as two table. It is the same table. just replace table with whatever your name of your table

Answer (score 0):

```
select q1.parameter, q2.result as r1, q3.result as r2
  from 
    (select distinct parameter from temp2) q1
    left join (select parameter, result from temp2 where job_id = 1) q2
      on q1.parameter = q2.parameter
    left join (select parameter, result from temp2 where job_id = 2) q3
      on q1.parameter = q3.parameter;
```

It works, but it's not efficient.  Still, since I'm gathering you are trying to solve something more complex than what's presented, this might help form your general solution.

While I'm at it, here's a slightly cleaner solution:

```
select distinct q1.parameter, q2.result as r1, q3.result as r2
  from 
    temp2 q1
    left join (select parameter, result from temp2 where job_id = 1) q2
      on q1.parameter = q2.parameter
    left join (select parameter, result from temp2 where job_id = 2) q3
      on q1.parameter = q3.parameter;
```